# Disk Image Clone Issues

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

So, here's my situation. I have a 1TB HDD that I want to clone onto a much faster 120GB SSD, without particular partitions. The software which came with the SSD, Acronis True Image HD, keeps running into issues, not letting me continue after selecting to ignore a partition when out of space and then encountering errors while copying, even when I have clear off enough free space on the HDD to fit all of the written files onto the SSD. I have another 1TB HDD external drive, though I'm using that for external files, which I would rather not lose (though I could back them up onto something else if I really needed to). Is there any software I could use to copy the GPT partition and make the SSD bootable? I find ways to copy individual partitions, but the drive has three partitions (an EFI partition, a generic Windows partition, and a Lenovo backup partition). In an ideal world, I would only carry over the Windows and maybe the EFI partition if necessary. What would be a good way to go about doing this?

Comment: Lots of people are having these same issues with many of the newer laptops.  Lenovo, Asus, HP, etc.  They are embedding the Windows key in the BIOS and some of the restore disks they let you build won't work moving a 1TB disk to a smaller 256GB disk.